# How to upgrade Atom from webupd8team/atom to the offical packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom

Tags: atom

Not until very recently you couldn't `apt install atom` unless you use an unoffical source [webupd8team/atom](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/atom). Now Atom officially supports `apt install` by [packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom](https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/). But upgrading 1.26.1-1~webupd8~0 to 1.33.0 using the official source resulted in an Atom that can't open any windows on my machine. e.g. No <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Comma</kbd>, no Welcome Guide, no About Atom.

After I re-installed the webupd8team version everything went back to normal. Then I tried everything. Before doing the following I `sudo apt purge atom` first.

1. Install from software center.
2. Install from `.deb`
3. Install 1.32.2 from `packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom`
4. Install 1.26.1 from `packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom`

4 worked!! Also the official 1.33.0 can be installed in my virtual machine which is running 18.04 and had a 1.26.1 webupd8team version installed before.

My best guess is it could be something in my system that is incompatible with 1.26+ (1.29.0 also presents the same symptom), and it's not on my virtual machine. What it could be?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I updated my question to record the progress on this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is atom installed from sources other than `webupd8team/atom` does not have permission to access `~/.atom/compile-cache`. `sudo apt purge atom` doesn't delete that folder. So atom gets denied when trying to access files in that folder.

By open the web console using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> you can see what error is occurring behind the scene.

The solution is easy. First, delete `~/.atom/compile-cache`. Then purge atom, fresh install atom from the source of your choice. Remember to remove the outdated ppa afterwards.

More info please refer to the thread [Problem with starting up atom](https://discuss.atom.io/t/problem-with-starting-up-atom-just-instant-error/41645)